# Put 10 balls in the jar then randomly take 1 out. Do it infinitely many times. Find the probability of resulting in an empty jar

Tags: pr.probability, infinite-sequences, paradox

The original discussion (in Chinese): https://www.zhihu.com/question/58702489

The original problem was from an probability theory exam. The problem is translated as:

> Assume an infinitely large jar and infinitely many balls $b_1, b_2, b_3, \dots$ outside the jar. At 1 minute before 12:00 a.m., put $b_1\sim b_{10}$ in the jar, then randomly take 1 ball out from the jar.(assume that these operations take no time) At 1/2 minute before 12:00 a.m., put $b_{11}\sim b_{20}$ in the jar, then randomly take 1 ball out from the jar. At 1/4 minute before 12:00 a.m., put $b_{21}\sim b_{30}$ in the jar, then randomly take 1 ball out from the jar. And so on. Question: what is the probability of the jar containing no ball at 12:00 a.m.?

There are two simple but contradictory answers:

- Zero. The number of balls always increases by each step, so it can never be zero.
- One. For each ball $b_i$, the probability of being inside the jar at 12:00 a.m. is $p_i=\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{18}{19}\cdot\frac{27}{28}\cdot\dots =0$. Let $X_i$ be a 0-1 random variable indicating whether the ball is in the jar, we can obtain the expectation of number of balls in the jar, which is $E[\sum_i X_i]=\sum_i E[X_i]=\sum_i p_i=0$

From the original discussion, it seems that this paradox is not trivial at all. Most people argue that the problem was not well-defined, but some disagree (like this: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/26460906). What is your opinion?

Comment: Further search lead me to this wikipedia page describing a very similar problem called [Ross-LIttlewood Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox)

Comment: I think that the mathematical problem implicit in the question (at least in my interpretation) is not a problem for research mathematicians.  But I think it should be stated clearly that there is no paradox.

Comment: I know a simpler paradox: At the $n$-th step add the balls from $n^2$ to $(n+1)^2-1$ and then remove the $n$-th ball. How many balls are left after infinitely many steps? This has nothing to do with probability.

Comment: I have a hard time finding anything paradoxical about this: We have an unlimited supply of balls, and we put some of them into an urn while keeping the prob for each individual ball of finding itself in the urn small. I don't think there's anything funny about that. (For example, the US has a large number of senators, but the probability for any given individual of being a senator is negligible.)

Comment: @Christian Remling: Apply analysis and consider seriously the unlimited supply. Then it is clear that the jar cannot be empty at any time after start. The contrary result forgets about the unlimited supply and applies the wrong idea that infinity could be finished .

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what would happen in the physical world.  But this particular problem can be rewritten (formulated? interpreted?) as a purely mathematical problem as follows.

Let $x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ be a sequence of natural numbers with 
$x_n\in \{ 1,\ldots, 9n+1\}$.

We define a sequence $(A_0, A_1,A_2,\ldots)$ of a finite subsets of $\{ 1,2,\ldots\}$.   (Depending  on $x$, so they should be written as $A_0^x$, etc.)

$A_1 = \{1,\ldots, 10\}$, and $B_1 = A_1 \setminus \{k_1\}$, where $k_1$ is the $x_1$-th element of $A_1$.

$A_2= B_1 \cup \{ 10n-9,\ldots, 10n\}$, and $B_2 = A_2 \setminus \{k_2\}$, 
where $k_2$ is the $x_2$-th element of $A_2$.

Etc.  Each $A_n$ has $9n+1$ elements, and $B_n$ has $9n$ elements.

There is a naturally defined limit of these sets $A_n$ (although it is unclear to me whether this limit has anything to do with the "real world". 
For any such sequence $(A_n^x: n =1,2,\ldots)$, the "lower limit" $\bigcap _n \bigcup_{k\ge n} A_k^x$ and the "upper limit" $\bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\ge n} A_k^x$  are the same set, which I will call $A^x_\infty$.

Now the question can be rephrased as follows:

- What do we know about the set $S$ of all $x$ such that $A^x_\infty = \emptyset$?
- What do we know about the set of all $x$ such that $A^x_\infty$ is *your favorite property here*?  (Is finite. Has positive density. Contains only prime numbers. etc.)

You already argued that set $S$ has measure 1, if we use the usual product measure (with equidistribution on all factors) on the set of all possible $x$.  It seems also clear to me that this set is co-meager (=residual).

In conclusion: there is no paradox, but you have to explain what "randomly" means. I gave *one* possible interpretation.

Comment: A paradox is that so many set theorists stress the contrary and completely neglect mathematics where the (improper) analytical limit of the sequence of cardinal numbers significantly differs from the cardinal number of the set-theoretic limit. It is obvious that the set-theoretic limit is wrong (not only with respect to mathematics but also in reality) because the supply of balls does never end and the jar cannot become empty.